# No Output Directory named "build" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings

Tags: reactjs, express, build, vercel, build-error

```
Error: No Output Directory named "build" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.
```

i got this error here is my repository https://github.com/Excell-09/find-job

i want to fix this error when i deploy on vercel

Answer (score 9):

In my case i just had to put a dot in Output Directory section :

[image]

Comment: Holy cow that worked for me... but WHY?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue deploying on Vercel. What worked for me was changing the Output Directory to `/dist` like so,

[image]

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and since I was new to the Vercel environment I could not figure out where to get the settings.

If you are running into this error when building the likely cause as stated above is the framework selection.

In these three steps, you should select Vercel then build and deploy again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here your build directory is inside `public` folder. so you've to edit the build directory setting in your vercel settings for the project. by default it looks for the `public` path. now you're build folder is `client/public`.
you to edit this output directory

[image: vercel deploy setting of output directory]

Answer (score 0):

This error also happened to me, but because my svelte.config.js was set to adapter-node. It must be either:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
```

or

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-vercel';
```